# Make TextView appears and disappears by clicking

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have two TextViews. My goal is to make 1st TextView clickable. If you click on it second activity appears. If you click again, it disappears. I did it clickable and 2nd activity appears after clicking, but I don't know how to make it disappears after clicking by 1st activity.

I do it in this way:

```
1st.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        2nd.setText(R.string.2nd_text);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
1st.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(2st.getVisibility==View.INVISIBLE){
              2st.setVisible(View.VISIBLE)
        } else{
            2st.setVisible(View.INVISIBLE)
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

var names never start with a number!!

try `1st.setVisible(View.INVISIBLE);`

if you want to toggle visibility you can use:

```
if(2st.getVisibility==View.INVISIBLE){
    2st.setVisible(View.VISIBLE)
} else{
    2st.setVisible(View.INVISIBLE)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did it for clarity. In real app I use different names.

Comment: partially, I need to make it visible after second click.

Comment: how will someone know that you can click a not visible textview?

Comment: no, I click a 1st -> second appears, I click 1st again -> second disappears.